# Compare MySQL row against PHP array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare IP addresses in a list against a list of blocked IPs.  If the IP address is equal to an address in the $blockedIP array, the row is not included in the list. The list is populated from a mysqli_query.  What I would like to do is exclude the whole row if the IP address matches one in the array.

```
echo '<div class="genericTable"><h2>Downloaded Sermons Report</h2><table>';

$blockedIP = array('69.58.178.58', '173.199.115.123', '173.199.120.99');

foreach($blockedIP as $ip){
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dl_log WHERE ipaddress <> '".$ip."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo '<tr>';

    if($row['ipaddress'] !== $ip){
        foreach($row as $each){
            echo '<td class="genericTable">'.$each.'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
echo '</table></div>';
```

I've tried the script a few different ways and either get the whole list or every row & column are compared to the array, which makes for a jacked up looking table.  I'm using the foreach to compare values to the array.  Where should I put it?
Thanks.

Comment: you know blocking IP's, is pointless right? IP != user. One IP could be million of people, and one person could use a new IP for every request.

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid a row, just do your check _before_ printing the row...

Comment: Dagon, I'm not blocking IPs from access, just from showing up on a list. The entire script analyzes IPs of users that have downloaded files, when they were downloaded, etc. The blocked IPs appear to be search engine robots. I don't want to bloat the table with unnecessary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to do is exclude the whole row if the IP address matches one in the array.

You have a few options:

1. One query using SQL [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). Condense the blocked IP address with [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode).

   ```
   SELECT * FROM dl_log WHERE ipaddress NOT IN (...);
   ```
2. One query and use PHP `in_array()` to filter he results

   ```
   // SQL
   SELECT * FROM dl_log;

   // PHP
   if (!in_array($row['ipaddress'], $blockedIP))
   ```

Comment: and if its search engines you want to stop, use robots.txt file or useragent analysis . far more efficient, bot ips change all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not print the row out, change

```
if($row['ipaddress'] !== $ip){
```

to

```
if(!in_array($row['ipaddress'], $blockedIP)){
```